# HTTP 500 response and white screen while trying to deploy laravel 8 app to hostinger shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, cpanel, shared-hosting

The title sums up my issue. I'm deploying to shared hosting by uploading my files (except `mylaravelproject/public/` to the root directory, and the contents of `mylaravelproject/public/` to `public_html/`.

I've already tried the following:

- Configuring `index.php` to point to the correct folder in root
- Running `composer install` and `npm install` in the relevant directory
- `php artisan key:generate`
- `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`
- `composer dump-autoload`
- Configuring `.env` and changing the relevant fields: `APP_URL` and database related ones

I'm still met with a white screen and an HTTP 500 error. What should I do?

Comment: Check the logs to find out what the error is

Comment: A 500 error is just a generic error message that can mean anything. You need to check the web servers error log to find the real error message. Without that, anything would just be guesses.

Comment: attach the error logs here, also enable debug true for you project so it can display the error message

Comment: You've to configure your public/index.php file to direct towards bootstrap autoload and to vendor path. Once that's done then you can easily deploy it to shared server

Answer (score 1):

Whoops! I was able to solve it on my own somehow. Thanks to everyone who replied still.

For anyone having similar issues:

Start by adding the following to the top of `index.php`:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Turns out hpanel / hostinger's directory structure is weird, and `public_html/` from the file manager is actually a shortcut to a folder *not* directly under root. Here's what it actually looks like:

```
/
| - domains
    | - yourdomainname.com
        | - public_html
            | - index.php
```

So unlike most guides out there, relevant directories under `index.php` need to be changed to something like `__DIR__.'/../../../laravelinrootname/storage/framework/maintenance.php'`

Answer (score 0):

Enable debugger to know the issue

inside **Config/App.php** change

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false)
```

to

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)
```

& in .env make `APP_DEBUG=` true

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```